# Jconsole cannot connect

Tags: java, linux, vnc, jconsole

I am using VNC to connect to a server. I am able to VNC into the server, and open Jconsole, but cannot get it to connect to my process whether I include the PID or try connecting using the GUI. The weird thing is all the processes show up in the GUI. See below.

[image]

I get this when I try connecting:

[image]

Followed by

[image]

Is there something I need to do in order to get Jconsole working locally on a Linux server over VNC?

Comment: There's nothing you need to do that would be different from doing it sitting at the physical keyboard. Does the `ts_watchdog` program disallow VM management?

Comment: No I run the same program from the same Executable Jar as a service using nohup java -jar [path] &    ; Then I run jconosle PID and I am connected. If it makes a difference my laptop is a mac and the server is ubuntu.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fix found [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1177644): You need to pass to the VM:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
```

--
Edit - Fixed the `=fals` error mentioned in comments.

Comment: At the end of the line it is not **fals**, but **false**. But it is ok! Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I also had to add this option to get Jconsole to connect to the process.

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost

Comment: this also required in MAC I guess.

Comment: yup, this fixed the issue for me and I'm running jconsole from a mac terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Remote JConsole

Add the following parameters to your java Application and run it

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=DOMAIN_PUBLIC_URL  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=PORTNUMBER -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

`DOMAIN_PUBLIC_URL` - Like your instance public address

`PORTNUMBER` - 9955

Launch jconsole in your ubuntu from terminal command and go to remote connection and paste the DOMAIN_PUBLIC_URL and PORT and Connect it without username and password like insecure connection.

Make sure to expose the port number on your AWS Server Instance.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to make it false and also add a hostname to localhost. Add this in VM arguments in Run Configurations.

> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding below property as VM argument in Run Configurations --> Arguments --

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
```